# Rely on .pgpass in CREATE USER MAPPING

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, foreign-data

I am trying to create a script which creates a postgres-fdw connection between two postgres 9.4 databases. The script (which is checked in under version control), has been relying on pgpass to do other things. Is there any option I can use to request that the password be looked up in pgpass? ... in general, where is the documentation on what options are available for `CREATE USER MAPPING`? the [reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createusermapping.html) just says that options depend on the server.

Comment: The 'server' in this context refers to the one in `CREATE SERVER` statement, and its documentation further redirects to that of the [foreign data wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html).  It further says: _'CREATE USER MAPPING [...] Specify connection information, except user and password, as options of the server object.'_  I think, as `.pgpass` is a client thing, it cannot be used in this context.

Comment: Your reasoning sounds good... hmm... fdw is acting as a client to the server -- it *could* have an option to look in a .pgpass local to the server, for which security would be more easily maintained than if I have to put in my script. Not saying it does, of course. Still would be nice to see where the options are documented, although "except for user and password" would make it seem that these are the only ones for "create user mapping". ... thanks!

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: As of PostgreSQL 13 this is now possible with `password_required=false`, see [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/postgres-fdw.html#id-1.11.7.42.10)

It may not fully answer your question, but:

If you specify a user mapping for a `superuser` for `postgres_fdw` you can specify it without a password. It will then rely on the `.pgpass` from the server.

By using a mapping for a `superuser` you will however need to think about what security concerns this raises for your usage.

Data source:

- dbname=sales
- host=sales.db
- user=sales_reader

Own DB:

- dbname=dwh
- host=dwh.db
- user=dwh_writer
- `~/.pgpass` of the `postgres` OS user contains:        `sales.db:*:sales:sales_reader:verysecret`

Example session showing the difference between `NOSUPERUSER` and `SUPERUSER`:

```
CREATE SERVER sales FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
    OPTIONS (host 'sales.db', dbname 'sales');
GRANT USAGE ON FOREIGN SERVER sales TO dwh_writer;
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR dwh_writer SERVER sales OPTIONS (user 'sales_reader');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres   SERVER sales OPTIONS (user 'sales_reader');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE sales_summary (
    item_id text,
    amount bigint,
    date_sold date
)
SERVER sales
OPTIONS (schema_name 'sales_data', table_name 'sales_summary');

GRANT SELECT ON sales_summary TO dwh_writer;

\c dwh dwh_writer

dwh_writer@dwh=> SELECT count(*) FROM sales_summary;
ERROR:  password is required
DETAIL:  Non-superusers must provide a password in the user mapping.

\c dwh postgres

postgres@dwh=# SELECT count(*) FROM sales_summary;
 count
-------
     2
(1 row)
```

Comment: That won't fly for me because of security issues... at least for the moment. However, contains a good idea and have upvoted. Thanks!

Comment: Can I create another linux user for an existing postgresql user and then use this user's `.pgpass` ? In your case if a user `dwh_writer` exists in my OS would the user's `.pg_pass` be used?